# how to check a particular field value exist in another object list

Tags: apex

I have two object lists,I need to check if a particular unique field exist in other list ,if not i have to collect those in a set for query purpose

```
for(Integer i=0;i<purchaseLineItemListToShow.size();i++)
{
    for(Integer j=0;j<stockItems.size();j++)
    {
        if(purchaseLineItemListToShow[i].Unique_Product_ID__c==stockItems[j].Unique_Product_ID__c)
        {
            //some logic
        }
        else
        {
            Uniqueidslist.add(purchaseLineItemListToShow[i].Unique_Product_ID__c);
        }
    }
}
```

here I want get all Unique_Product_ID__c's list from  purchaseLineItemListToShow list which are not existed in stockItems list

Comment: Can you use Sets? If so I would consider using them and implementing the [conatins](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm) method when checking to see if the field already exists in other Set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is an obvious use case for `Set`. It's unclear what else you may be using `stockItems` for, so it's hard to say if you can just change its type to `Set<String>`. Even if you can't for some reason, you can add a separate variable.

```
Set<String> existingIds = new Set<String>(stockItems);
for(Integer i=0;i<purchaseLineItemListToShow.size();i++)
{
    String productId = purchaseLineItemListtoShow[i].Unique_Product_Id__c;
    if (existingIds.contains(productId))
    {
        // some logic
    }
    else
    {
        uniqueIdsList.add(productId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Set` collection type is your friend here.

It has a few helpful methods like `removeAll(Set)` and `retainAll(Set)` that will allow you to avoid using a nested loop.

The prerequisites are that you use two separate loops (one over `stockItems`, the other over `purchaseLineItemListToShow`) to gather your `Unique_Product_ID__c` field values into two separate `Set<String>` variables.

From there, you can clone, and use `retainAll()` and `removeAll()` to arrive at which `Unique_Product_ID__c` exist in both sets, and which exist in only one of the sets.

```
// Assuming we have Set<String> inStock, and Set<String> ordered, declared and already 
//   populated...

// Using clone() is necessary because retainAll() and removeAll() can modify the set
//   that they are called on, and we might need to reference the original sets
//   later on.
Set<String> orderedAndInStock = inStock.clone().retainAll(ordered);

// Once we have the set of elements that exist in both sets, we can obtain the set of 
//   elements that are only in one of the sets in a few different ways.
// This is just one way of doing it, though it's probably the easiest.
Set<String> notOrderedOrNotInStock = inStock.clone();

// Add all of the elements from 'ordered' to get the union of both sets.
// We don't need to worry about duplicates in a Set.
notOrderedOrNotInStock.addAll(ordered);


// The set of everything, minus the set of things that were both ordered and in stock,
//   leaves us with the things that were either in stock but not ordered, or
//   ordered but not in stock
norOrderedOrNotInStock.removeAll(orderedAndInStock);
```